# flutter scrolling does not work: ListView and SingleChildScrollView

Tags: flutter, scroll

I have been reading solutions for making my screen scroll without success. Below is my code:
'''

```
class WelcomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  static const String id = 'welcome_screen';

  @override
  _WelcomeScreenState createState() => _WelcomeScreenState();
}

class _WelcomeScreenState extends State<WelcomeScreen>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  AnimationController controller;
  Animation animation;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    controller =
        AnimationController(duration: Duration(seconds: 1), vsync: this);
    animation = ColorTween(begin: Colors.blueGrey, end: Colors.white)
        .animate(controller);
    controller.forward();
    controller.addListener(() {
      setState(() {});
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: animation.value,
      body: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 24.0),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          children: <Widget>[
            Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Hero(
                  tag: 'logo',
                  child: Container(
                    child: Image.asset('images/logo.png'),
                    height: 60.0,
                  ),
                ),
                TypewriterAnimatedTextKit(
                  text: ['Tonnah'],
                  textStyle: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 45.0,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 48.0,
            ),
            RoundedButton(
              title: 'Log In',
              colour: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.pushNamed(context, LoginScreen.id);
              },
            ),
            RoundedButton(
              title: 'Register',
              colour: Colors.blueAccent,
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.pushNamed(context, RegistrationScreen.id);
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

'''
I have tried ListView and SingleChildScrollView but nothing works. This is a registration page that I will use to capture information about the user. I don't know if this is the best way of doing this or if I should be getting the user to fill out a profile after they register with their email and password.

I am new to flutter and mobile app development so please help?

TIA

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap your Column with SingleChildScrollView()

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I have tried that and it didn't work. I have redesigned that page but will need it on another page so I will try it again.